# Why can't assign anything to my left hand?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I was messing around under 'controls' in settings, then suddenly mouse2 did not work anymore. I have no configuration showing for left hand. I can't use mouse2 to block anymore either. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It sounds like you need to rebind your keys. I recommend you set mouse1 to left hand and mouse2 to right hand, it's so much easier to be left handed in Skyrim.

Comment: _Please,_ add the pc tag, I thought you meant  XBOX 360 version of Skyrim. Or at least say you play on the pc in your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press T in the control menu. It should reset the controls to default, and "Left Hand" should be accessible.

Answer (score 3):

In the game directory, delete the file "ControlMap_Custom.txt"
this will restore all the default key assignments. 
The file will be recreated as soon as you reassign any key.

Answer (score 2):

You either accidental assigned the "mouse 2" to another key or you asigned something else to mouse 2 and thus, the original "mouse 2" command has no key. If you go back into the controls there should be a reset controls button or something that changes the controls back to the way they were. If not, you will simply have to re-assigning the "mouse 2" control yourself.

Comment: There is no reset button in the controls section. Also, like I said, there is no left hand option in the controls menu. I noticed a guy here has my exact same problem;  http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111113182943AAo81ly However nobody has answered.

Comment: @cc0 Well, if all else fails, you can always try re-installing the game.

Comment: That's more non-advice.